# Bitcoin transaction confirmed over 500 times yet the funds are not showing up

Tags: transactions, funds

Here is the transaction id# 80aa5b554a1d5df2fda472832d76a2251dd0bc84d73e98343dedfffc92d7141e

Comment: I sent the Bitcoin to my other wallet I used the correct address and correct wallet type

Answer (score 2):

As [mam5](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/141793/mam5) [wrote](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/118058/13866), the money was received and then spent the same day.

At Apr 23, 2023, 12:18 AM UTC, Address 3H9eTMPu4i4ryghDvn83Z8FZBR3bAjFnGT received 0.01815985 BTC from your transaction 80aa5b554a1d5df2fda472832d76a2251dd0bc84d73e98343dedfffc92d7141e

Then, almost two hours later :

At  Apr 23, 2023, 2:16 AM UTC, Address 3H9eTMPu4i4ryghDvn83Z8FZBR3bAjFnGT sent 0.01815985 BTC using a new transaction fea781fc52ec6d5a9f615efef90042cfb5f7c3edaa9d0aecab0933917d82a89d

If address 3H9eTMPu4i4ryghDvn83Z8FZBR3bAjFnGT is yours and you didn't create the second transaction, either your wallet is fake or someone else has copies of the keys it contains.

Remember, Bitcoin wallets don't contain money, they contain keys.

---

- https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/80aa5b554a1d5df2fda472832d76a2251dd0bc84d73e98343dedfffc92d7141e
- https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/address/3H9eTMPu4i4ryghDvn83Z8FZBR3bAjFnGT

Comment: So I have been scammed somehow? I don't understand what happened did I do something wrong

Comment: @Russell: see amended answer

Answer (score 1):

As per [mempool](https://mempool.space/tx/80aa5b554a1d5df2fda472832d76a2251dd0bc84d73e98343dedfffc92d7141e), it was already spent